# How to add and reference a map of map as a local variable in terraform?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I want to create a map of map as a local variable. I am using this

```
locals {
  region_map = {
     mumbai = {
       is_second_execution = true
       cg_ip_address       = "ip.add.re.ss"
    }
  }
}
```

Now I am referencing it as

```
module "mumbai" {
  source                    = "./site-to-site-vpn-setup"
  providers                 = { aws = aws.mumbai }
  is_second_execution       = lookup(local.region_map, local.region_map["mumbai"]["is_second_execution"], false)
  cg_ip_address             = lookup(local.region_map, local.region_map["mumbai"]["cg_ip_address"], "")
}
```

but upon doing terrafrom plan the cg_ip_address is being set to null.
Also If I add another module say "saopaulo" and I need to pass default values of is_second_execution and cg_ip_address for it without adding saopaulo in the map, how do I do that?

Comment: Its not clear what you mean. Can you demonstrate the code where you get null?

Comment: if I add another module for "saopaulo" but don't add the local variables for it in the region_map. Now I want to check if saopaulo is added in region_map and if it is not added then I want to set default value for is_second_execution as false and cg_ip_address as empty when calling the module, so how to do that? If I use is_second_execution       = lookup(local.region_map.saopaulo, "is_second_execution", false)
  cg_ip_address             = lookup(local.region_map.saopaulo, "cg_ip_address", "") then I get Error: Unsupported attribute

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `lookup` built-in function [1] has the following syntax:

> lookup(map, key, default)

Since you have a map of maps, that means that the first argument is the map (`local.region_map.mumbai`), the second is the key you are looking for (`cg_ip_address`) and the third argument is the default value. So in your case you have to change the lookup to this:

```
module "mumbai" {
  source                    = "./site-to-site-vpn-setup"
  providers                 = { aws = aws.mumbai }
  is_second_execution       = lookup(local.region_map.mumbai, "is_second_execution", false)
  cg_ip_address             = lookup(local.region_map.mumbai, "cg_ip_address", "")
}
```

---

[1] https://www.terraform.io/language/functions/lookup

Comment: Thank you this works, now if I want to add another module like 
module "saopaulo" {
  source                    = "./site-to-site-vpn-setup"
  providers                 = { aws = aws.saopaulo }
  is_second_execution       = 
  cg_ip_address             = 
}
but I don't add the values for it in the region_map as it is the first execution. I want to check if it is added in the map and if it isn't then I want to set the default value for is_second_execution as false and cg_ip_address as empty so how to do that?

Comment: That is a different question compared to the original one and should be a separate question. You could do a lookup in the locals for `saopaulo` and set it to default values the same way you would when calling a module.

Comment: if i do --->  is_second_execution       = lookup(local.region_map.saopaulo, "is_second_execution", false).  then I get Error: Unsupported attribute
│ 
│  on main.tf line 20, in module "saopaulo":
│  20:  is_second_execution    = lookup(local.region_map.saopaulo, "is_second_execution", false)
│   ├────────────────
│   │ local.region_map is object with 1 attribute "mumbai"
│ 
│ This object does not have an attribute named "saopaulo".

Comment: As I've mentioned, it's another question with a different problem, so please ask that, since my answer resolved your initial issue.

Comment: Thanks, if you can answer it then here is the link https://stackoverflow.com/q/72696020/19372445